# Indexing a list in python and looping through these

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list:

```
{'5ogb.pdb': [[['ASN', 15.0, 'A'], 8.0], [['ASN', 26.0, 'A'], 12.0]]}
```

and I am trying to loop through the:

```
['ASN', 15.0, 'A'] and ['ASN', 26.0, 'A']
```

How do I index to be able to loop through only these values?

Comment: This is a dictionary not a list. That aside, just do `for i in s['5ogb.pdb']: print(i[0])`

Comment: your original object is `dict` of `list` not a `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop through your `dict` (yes its a dictionary not a `list), and print first item,

```
x = {'5ogb.pdb': [[['ASN', 15.0, 'A'], 8.0], [['ASN', 26.0, 'A'], 12.0]]} 
for list_object in x['5ogb.pdb']:
        print(list_object[0])

# output,
['ASN', 15.0, 'A']
['ASN', 26.0, 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a dictionary that has one key-value pair. Get the list by saying `dict[key]` and you can loop through it with like this:

```
for list1, list2 in zip(dict[key][0], dict[key][1]):
    #more code
```

`zip()` lets you iterate through both lists at the same time.